# SQLGrammarException on Heroku after local database change

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, heroku

I created a Java webapp that uses Hibernate and PostgreSQL. It is based on Heroku's Java MVC tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/spring-mvc-hibernate). I made some minor database changes and correctly update all hibernate annotation. Everything works fine locally, but after pushing to Heroku, I now get this error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

...

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "MY_TABLE" does not exist
```

So it seems the database changes which exist on my local machine are not reflected up in the heroku cloud. How can I get Heroku to "reset" or "rebuild" my database?

**Update** - I ran `heroku pg:reset` and it threw an "Internal server error" telling me to "Run 'heroku status' to check for known platform issues", however running that gave no info. I then checked the site and it was working again (no data of course, but that was expected). Not sure what really happened, but that fixed the problem. Of course, it helps that i was ok with losing all my data.

Comment: It's also possible that your table was created as `my_table` and you're trying to query it as `"MY_TABLE"`. PostgreSQL lower-cases identifiers unless they are double quoted - as per the standard - so you must quote everywhere, or nowhere. Connect with `psql` and use '\dt` to see, or use JDBC to run `SELECT table_name, table_schema FROM information_schema.tables WHERE lower(table_name) = 'my_table';` and see if there's a result.

Comment: @craig-ringer - Thanks for your suggestion. The table name is in lowercase, I just put in "MY_TABLE" for my initial post. I ran the query and it returns the expected result, so I think everything is ok on that end.

Comment: I had a similar problem when table was in different schema (check it). Did you run 'heroku run rake db:migrate'? Try also (after running migrate) push empty (no change) commit. If nothing helps and you can destroy all data on heroku just run 'heroku db:push' (but remember that it will destroy all data on heroku and send copy of your local database there !!).

Comment: @sufleR Thanks, I ran `heroku pg:reset` and it seemed to work.